# Populating DataTable from Nested JSON in a Declarative Way

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have an API that returns the following `JSON`:

```
{ "data": [
    {
        "sensors": [
            {
                "description": "Second Sensor",
                "value": 6.0
            },
            {
                "description": "My Default Sensor",
                "value": 8.0
            }
        ],
        "timestamp": "2018-04-01T00:00:00"
    },
    {
        "sensors": [
            {
                "description": "Second Sensor",
                "value": 8.0
            },
            {
                "description": "My Default Sensor",
                "value": 6.0
            }
        ],
        "timestamp": "2018-03-31T23:59:59"
    }
] }
```

I want to render only the first element `data[0]` within a `DataTable`.

```
<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-hover" id="dataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Sensor</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

I am expecting it to show:

```
Second Sensor          6.0
My Default Sensor      8.0
```

Can I do that in a declarative way with `DataTables` or do I have to modify the returned data by the API with client-side `JavaScript`, which I then pass to the `DataTable`?

---

The following code is not quite what I seek for since it always displays only one sensor.

```
$('#dataTable').DataTable({          
    ajax: 'myapiurl',
    columns: [
        { "data": "sensors.0.description" },
        { "data": "sensors.0.value" 
    ]
});
```

Comment: Did you try replacing sensors.0.XYZ with sensors[0].XYZ for both the occurrences in the last code snippet

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't end in the expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with the following solution:

```
$.getJSON('url', function (response) {
    var dataSet = response.data[0].sensors;

    $('#dataTable').DataTable({
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { data: "description" },
            { data: "value" }
        ]
    });
});
```